# Why can't object_set get unique items?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pull a user's objects viewed from the Product model. It's pulling all of the user's viewed products right now but with duplicates. I have tried putting .distinct() in

```
views = request.user.objectviewed_set.by_model(Product, model_queryset=False).distinct()
```

but it does not work, I think because that is just pulling the rows for Object viewed, not the products themselves.

Appreciate the help!

**from html**

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    <div class='col-xl-12'>
    {% include 'products/card.html' with instance=obj.content_object %}  
    
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**from products/card.html**

```
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">

<a href="{{instance.get_absolute_url}}">
    <img style="width:30%;" src="{{instance|get_thumbnail:'sd'}}" alt="{{instance.title}} logo">
</a>

<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title">{{ instance.title }}</h4>
<p class="card-text">{{ instance.description|linebreaks|truncatewords:14 }}</p>
</div>
```

**from products models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
seller      = models.ForeignKey(SellerAccount, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title       = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
slug        = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

def __str__(self): #defining str as self and returning self, which is used ie in admin.py
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    view_name = "products:detail"
    return reverse(view_name, kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

**from analytics models.py**

```
class ObjectViewedQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def by_model(self, model_class, model_queryset=False):
        c_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model_class)
        qs = self.filter(content_type=c_type)
        if model_queryset:
            viewed_ids = [x.object_id for x in qs]
            return model_class.objects.filter(pk__in=viewed_ids)
        return qs

class ObjectViewedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ObjectViewedQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def by_model(self, model_class, model_queryset=False):
        return self.get_queryset().by_model(model_class, model_queryset=model_queryset)
    
class ObjectViewed(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True) # User instance instance.id
    ip_address          = models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True) #IP Field
    content_type        = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE,) # User, Product, Order, Cart, Address
    object_id           = models.PositiveIntegerField() # User id, Product id, Order id,
    content_object      = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id') # Product instance
    timestamp           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = ObjectViewedManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s viewed on %s" %(self.content_object, self.timestamp)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp'] # most recent saved show up first
        verbose_name = 'Object viewed'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Objects viewed'


def object_viewed_receiver(sender, instance, request, *args, **kwargs):
    c_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(sender) # instance.__class__
    user = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
    new_view_obj = ObjectViewed.objects.create(
                user = user,
                content_type=c_type,
                object_id=instance.id,
                ip_address = get_client_ip(request)
        )


object_viewed_signal.connect(object_viewed_receiver)
```

**from products views.py**

```
class UserProductHistoryView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
template_name = "dashboard/history.html"
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(UserProductHistoryView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    return context

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = self.request
    views = request.user.objectviewed_set.by_model(Product, model_queryset=False)[:5]
    return views
```

Comment: That seems to be what the `model_queryset` parameter is for: to get a queryset of `Product`s rather than of `ObjectViewed` objects.

Comment: @tiffinie, In my opinion, your queryset cannot contain duplicates because you are filtering by `pk__in`:  `return model_class.objects.filter(pk__in=viewed_ids)`. How did you detect duplicates?

Comment: @NKSM I think the view is executing qs = self.filter(content_type=c_type) instead of model_queryset. Cos even if I hide that if subquery, it still generates the same output (with duplicate product items). If I force it to execute the model_queryset, it generates items from Product model, but no longer unique to the user and not in the order of last viewed.